# Hold and get ListView Item index

Tags: c#, listview, windows-phone, runtime

I have a `ListView` with the following items:

```
1. One
2. Two
3. Three
4. Four
5. Five
```

When I hold one of this itens my hold event is fired and I get the content and the index of the item, but for me get the index I have to have press it before I hold it. I need to get the index when I hold the item, not having to press it before.

here is my code

```
private void ListViewItem_Holding(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
{  
    content = (sender as ListViewItem).Content.ToString();
    index = historico.SelectedIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
private void ListViewItem_Holding(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
{  
    var item = (sender as FrameWorkElement).DataContext;
    //find index
    // index= yourItemSource.IndexOf(item );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. I fixed it putting the sender inside the IndexOf, just like these `index= yourItemSource.IndexOf(sender);`

Comment: But your answer was very helpfull